# Maven without the mouse

Tags: maven, ide

I thought maven was a way to build a project without relying on your IDE.  I've been following instructions that involve my IDE only to find the project only works from within the IDE.

I happen to be using intellij but I wish I didn't even have to tell you that.  Am I wrong or is there a way to build a maven project using keystrokes not "click this, then that" mouse instructions that change lord knows what in the IDE.  A way that will work within an IDE but not be dependent on that IDE?

I'm hoping I have been following some instructions that simply didn't have this as a goal.  Is there a way to build a maven project that will work just as well in intellij as eclipse?  If so how do I find it?  Is there a keyword I need to know to search for?

I'm probably misunderstanding something but I hope I've made my goal of having my project only depend on maven itself clear.

Comment: Maven is a command-line tool. IDEs happen to provide maven integration. I'm not even sure what the issue is--the Maven docs specifically tell you how to run it from your shell: http://maven.apache.org/run.html

Comment: Using the command line or shell on linux...will do the trick...

Comment: Yet to my horror I'm finding things like "view effective pom" which shows me a generated pom file I can't edit. - you shouldn't be able to edit the effective POM. It's a derived "file" coming from your actual pom and all parents. This isn't an IDE problem.

Comment: I have experiences using maven via eclipse integration, from command line (Windows 7) and via IntelliJ IDEA. For me, using maven from IntelliJ IDEA is the most comfortable way. But that's only my point of view...

Answer (score 1):

You can build a maven project from its directory using -

```
mvn clean install
```

Of course this requires Maven installed on the machine you are running it from.

Please look further into the documentation [here](http://maven.apache.org/run.html) as well.

Comment: You just proved exactly what I was afraid of.  Running that command shows errors the IDE didn't.  I guess I simply can't use an IDE at all to build a maven project.

Comment: @CandiedOrange you need to put things clear in terms of what do you want to achieve and what are you facing. Please do so in the question itself then. IMO subsequent errors if any should be debugged further and resolved and not be related to the same thread.

Comment: I'm facing tons of online documentation that tells me how to set up maven in my IDE and projects in my IDE that when followed produce a maven project that only works in my IDE. I'm looking for instructions that show how to avoid that. Your answer was to just not use the IDE to build. Which might be the only good answer.